# Maximize Multi-parameter summation with python

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, minimize

I am trying to fit a wind data set `v=v1,.....,vm` using a two component mixture weibull distribution.

I found a paper suggesting to use the Maximum Likelihood method and in particular to maximize the following equation:

[image: equation to maximize]

`Omega`, `a1`, `a2`, `b1` and `b2` are the parameters I want to change in order to maximize the function and `v=v1,.....,vm` is a series of known wind speeds.

I have been trying to use the SciPy minimization algorithm but without success.

Here is what I have so far:

```
def minimizer_function(v,omega,a1,b1,a2,b2):
   return np.reciprocal(np.sum((omega*(a1/b1)*((v/b1)**(a1-1))*(np.exp(-((v/b1)**a1)))+(1-omega)*(a2/b2)*((v/b2)**(a2-1))*(np.exp(-((v/b2)**a2))))))

x0 = np.array([0.5,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0])
res = optimization.minimize(minimizer_function, x0, method='nelder-mead',options={'xtol': 1e-8, 'disp': True})
```

However I keep on getting the following error:

> minimizer_function() missing 5 required positional arguments: 'omega', 'a1', 'b1', 'a2', and 'b2'

I am pretty sure I am missing something.

Answer (score 1):

The scipy minimizers expect the variables to be stored in a single one-dimensional array.  In your case, the objective function should be something like `minimizer_function(x, v)`, where `x` is an array of five elements containing omega, a1, b1, a2 and b2.  That is, something like

```
def minimizer_function(x, v):
   omega, a1, b1, a2, b2 = x
   return np.reciprocal(np.sum((omega*(a1/b1)*((v/b1)**(a1-1))*(np.exp(-((v/b1)**a1)))+(1-omega)*(a2/b2)*((v/b2)**(a2-1))*(np.exp(-((v/b2)**a2))))))
```

The call to `minimize` would be something like

```
x0 = np.array([0.5,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0])
res = optimization.minimize(minimizer_function, x0, args=(v,), method='nelder-mead',options={'xtol': 1e-8, 'disp': True})
```

Comment: Hi Warren, 
thank you very much for looking into this.
It runs now, the values look very strange but I am probably still missing something

Comment: Any suggestion on how to maximize the function?
At present I am minimizing the reciprocal of the abs of the function